# Ubuntu , Internet from two USB modems ?

Tags: 12.04, internet, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS . My question is , I have two USB dongles and i can connect them to PC (I have tried and connected both at a time ) But at a time system receiving Connection from only one Modem . Its not doing from two modems . so is it possible to get connection from Two modems ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## you can't

it is almost impossible to use more than one internet connection at a time. So the best way is install another os in virtual box, and use first tongle for host and another for guest